# IOS What version of TLS using While making NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

I am making Https connection with NSURLConnection so I wanted to know default What version of  Protocol(TLS) used.

How can I differentiate SSL/TLS and HTTP Protocol while making request.

Comment: The default is 1.2+. Please check this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33